# the method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSql' is currently not supported

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have one method like below -

```
public string SomeMethod() {

    var resultfromdb = from u in dbContext.TableOne.FromSql("Some select query here")
    join rm in dbContext.TableTwo on u.Id equals rm.FId
    select new SomeObject() {
        /* returning some prperty */
    };

    //some business code here
    return someresult;
}
```

Now, when I write Unit test for this method using Xunit i am facing below error on FromSql method

Error:

> **Could not parse expression** 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[TableOne]).FromSql(value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RawSqlString), __p_0)': This overload of the method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSql' is currently not supported.

Test Method

```
[Fact]
public void Test_Method()
{
 using (var context = new dbContext())
 {
  //Arrange
   PrefillData(context);//In this method i wll add some dummy data to dbcontext
   //some mocking for other code 

   //Act
   var result = SomeMethod();

   //Assert
   Assert.Equal(expectedString, result);
```

}

Comment: and how about this test's code?

Comment: Looks like you are using InMemory database for testing. As mentioned in the documentation, InMemory database does not support many database constructs, including SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using In-Memory Database. Since it is not a real database, you can't use FromSQL method.

Comment: Is there any alternative to test FromSQL?

Comment: @Voodoo If you look at the code in FromSql<T>, you can see that it makes a call to source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>. This is what you have to mock.

Comment: So can we use `source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>` directly in our main class.

Comment: I suggest that you configure a database provider for the DbContext. If you are going to use Entity Framework, use it as it is primarily intended and act on objects/entities

Comment: @Voodoo You can use the SQLite in-mem provider instead

Answer (score 0):

Change the `FromSql` to `FromSqlRaw`

```cs
dbContext.TableOne.FromSqlRaw("Some select query here")
```